# Numpy histogram split a value evenly in 2 bins

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, histogram

Let's say my orientation array is `[15,150]` and its respective magnitude is `[15,15]` My bins are `[0,45,90,135]` then I would like to split the magnitude `15` evenly into the bins with the output for `15` as its orientation: `[10,5,0,0]` and for the case of `150`, its `[5,0,0,10]` assuming its a **circular even distribution** of 0-180 degrees.

So assuming unsigned orientation of direction, (0-180 instead of 0-360), `15` is `15` degrees away from `0`, but it is `30` degrees away from `45`, so the weight is high towards `0` by `2/3` and low towards `45` by `1/3` of the magnitude for distribution.

Similarly for `150`, `150` is `15` degrees away from `135`, but it is `30` degrees away from `0` or `180`, so the weight is high towards `135` by `2/3` and low towards `0` by `1/3` of the magnitude for distribution.

It results into a histogram since the values would be assigned to pre-specified bins, but evenly distributed across the adjacent bins depending on how close it is.

How do I achieve that using the `np.histogram` or `np.bincount`? I tried the documentation of **numpy** but didn't find any accurate api that explicity mentions what I want.

Comment: Can you please explain how the output is obtained? I really do not understand why `15 -> [10,5,0,0]` and `150 -> [5,0,0,10]`...

Comment: @kazemakase Updated the question

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a histogram is.  Histograms sum values between bin edges, they don't assign values to bin edges.

Comment: @Mr.Robot I see, thank you for clarifying. This sounds more like a job for interpolation rather than histograms.

Comment: @DanielF Yes, it will be a summation of course. That was just explained as a proof of concept.

Comment: @kazemakase Well, it is a histogram since the values would be assigned to pre-specified bins, but evenly distributed across the adjacent bins depending on how close it is. Can you suggest me a solution to this job?

Comment: @Mr.Robot Explained like that it makes sense. I guess you will need a manual solution... have not heard of anything built in like that.

Comment: @kazemakase That's why I am here, for a manual solution. Can you reduct your flag on this question now?

Comment: @greg-449 can you reduct your flag now?

Comment: @mistalis can you reduct your flag now?

Comment: @Mr.Robot It's not possible to remove the flag. However, I have voted to reopen the question.